# How can I protect WCF service from unauthorized access?

Tags: c#, wcf

**EDIT:**

Please note two things: **application will be publicly available and users won't need to have any accounts**. You can also suggest other solution than WCF, if it's better.

I'm developing an application in C# which could install other applications easily. The list of programs supported by this application will be stored on a database on a public server. **Only my application** should be able to access this database. **Everyone** can install this application, and users **do not** need to have any accounts.

Now, I'm wondering how should the communication between app and server look like. I'm thinking of developing a WCF service, but everyone can connect easily to this service (only my program should access this service).

Is there any way to protect WCF service from unauthorized access? Or maybe do you have any better idea how should the communication between this app and server look like?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can check below links for help in this topic

```
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731925.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702565.aspx
```

You can configure your bindings to perform username and password based Authentication where you validated if the username and password are valid then only you can grant access to the service.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as I said, users do not need to have any accounts.

Answer (score -1):

NET has built in features for ensuring that the code calling yours is authorized to do so. For example, take a look at this snippet of code:

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "MyLocalSecurityGroup"]
public SearchResults Find(string contractNumber)
{
    // ...
}
```

Notice the [PrinciplePermission] attribute. This attribute tells .NET that only principals who are members of the "MyLocalSecurityGroup" role are allowed to run this method (where a principal is a user/service account, and a role is a locally defined security group on the server). In other words, in order to run this method, the caller must be running under an account that is a member of the local security group specified.

For more details of how to create the group click here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731200(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as I wrote, this application will be publicly available, so I don't think that it's a good solution (correct me if I'm wrong).